# Sqlite Vs Documents Directory

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite

I have store some files (audio) in Documents Directory . I want to know which is better Option for storing NSData?  Documents Directory or Sqlite?

Comment: is this an iPhone/Pad application?

Comment: Thanks PurplePilot.Its an Ipad App.Waiting for response .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sqlite3 to store audio data then it will take more space also it will reduce performance of your app. Saving NSData to file will be right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Both have their pros and cons. If you will have a lot (100+) of small files, keeping them in SQLite could be advantageous for caching and lookups. If you have only a handful of small files or they are large (over a MB each), keeping them in separate files would be simpler and faster.